# How to add Nomenclature in classic thesis template?

Tags: classicthesis, nomenclature

I am trying to add nomenclature page to classic thesis template. As I am new, I finding it difficult to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

In classicthesis-config.tex :

```
\usepackage[german,notintoc,norefeq,norefpage]{nomencl} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
%%%%%%%%%%% Nomencl als Section umdefiniert
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
\section*{\nomname}
\if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
\nompreamble
\list{}{%
\labelwidth\nom@tempdim
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\itemsep\nomitemsep
\let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{6em}
```

In Contents.tex :

```
% Formelzeichenverzeichnis
\clearpage
\phatomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature} % Oder intoc bei den Optionen
% \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\printnomenclature
```

Comment: (1) Put the simpler MWE from the **updated** answer,  `classicthesis-config.tex` and `classicthesis.sty`  in an empty directory (2) Compile  twice. (3) It will run `makeindex` by itself and produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Nomenclature output:

[image: a]

(1) Modify `classicthesis-config.tex`  (I called it `classicthesis-configx.tex`) by adding your block `\usepackage[german,notintoc,norefeq,norefpage]{nomencl} .. etc` before `\listfiles`

(2) Compile `Contents.tex`

(3) Run `makeindex Contents.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o Contents.nls` from a command windows open in the working directory.

You should see

```
Scanning input file Contents.nlo....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file Contents.nls....done (7 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in Contents.nls.
Transcript written in Contents.ilg.
```

(4)  Compile `Contents.tex` again.

This is the file  `Contents.tex`

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
]{scrreprt}% from the file ClassicThesis.tex

\input{classicthesis-configx} % from the package + added block

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

% Formelzeichenverzeichnis
\clearpage
\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature} % Oder intoc bei den Optionen
% \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

With a simpler MWE and using the original setup of the file `ClassicThesis.tex` will generate the desired output running `makeindex` by itself :

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}  % <<<added <<<<<< 

\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config} % from the package 

\usepackage[german]{nomencl} 

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Dispa, When I was trying the above steps I'm facing the following issues. 1->There is no content.nlo file in the template but I can find classicThesis.nlo. I tried with this file. 2-> When I say \begin{document} inside contents.tex a error saying  'Can be used only in preamble'  appears. I am compiling texStudio for your reference.

Comment: @pod (1) Put the simpler MWE from the **updated** answer, `classicthesis-config.tex` and `classicthesis.sty`  in an empty directory (2) Compile  twice,  (3) It will run `makeindex` by itself and produce the desired output.

Comment: Thank you @Simon, It works the additional piece of code that got added with the update sets the things right and displays the nomenclature in classicThesis template. Thank you once again.